# getting index based on class

Tags: jquery, indexing

I need to get the index of the element with class `.active` but seem unable to. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/litari/mo0ondxp/) demonstrating it (I've commented the line I'm interested in). If you press the pager-numbers it should display the correct index of the one marked red.

I have tried the following:

```
console.log($('.clickable').index('.active'));
console.log($('.pager').index('.active'));
console.log($('div.pager span.clickable').index('.active'));
console.log($('.active').index());
console.log($('.active').closest('.pager').find('.clickable').index('.active'));
console.log($('.clickable').index($('.clickable').filter('.active')));
console.log($('span.clickable').index('.active'));
console.log($('span.active').index());
console.log($('div.pager span.active').index());
```

This is how it appears in the HTML:

```
<div class="pager">
    <span class="page-number clickable">...</span>
    <span class="page-number clickable">2</span>
    <span class="page-number clickable active">3</span>
    <span class="page-number clickable">4</span>
    <span class="page-number clickable">...</span>
</div>
```

At this moment I'm just spamming different variations I've found on google/SO.. why won't anything work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to get the index of the element with class .active

Instead of

```
console.log($('.clickable.active').index('.active'));
```

do :

```
console.log($('.clickable.active').index());
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, but I'm still only getting '-1' all the time. Did it work for you in the fiddle?

Comment: According to your simple example  it is working . look here. http://jsbin.com/wuvalo/1/edit?html,js,output. you can't show html and ask about that html and supply another jsfiddle.

Comment: Hmm.. You're right. Do you mind having a look at my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/litari/mo0ondxp/2/) and see what I'm doing wrong?